# Dropdown box edit to trigger setValue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm looking for a way to use a dropdown(B5) trigger, just any edit, to copy the value of a cell(L6) to another(E3). I can't put the formula directly in the cell as I need to be able to edit it.

[image]

I've really hit a wall, the help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) in your script, this can be done by having specific function names, like [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

**Sample Code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "B5") {
     sheet.getRange("E3").setValue(sheet.getRange("L6").getValue()); 
  }
}
```

**Note:**

When you put this code in the script editor, if you run this manually (perhaps to authenticate), it will return an `TypeError` error. The script will run properly every time cell B5 is edited.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Enter Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 5) {
   sh.getRange(3,5).setValue(sh.getRange(5,2));
  }
}
```